# AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate setup issue

Tags: ios, ios7, avplayer, avasset

I have a weird issue when trying to setup AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate. When using this code it works most of the time on a device but it doesn't work on the simulator at all:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"xxx://name"];
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:url];

AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
[asset.resourceLoader setDelegate:self queue:self.queue];

AVPlayer *avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[avPlayer play];
```

The issue is that the delegate method is never getting called:

```
- (BOOL)resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:(AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest *)loadingRequest
```

However, this code works perfectly fine:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"xxx://name"];
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:url];

[asset.resourceLoader setDelegate:self queue:self.queue];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

AVPlayer *avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[avPlayer play];
```

The only difference is that we set the delegate first and then we create AVPlayerItem with the asset. In the first case, the asset is not being copied when creating AVPlayerItem and if we check playerItem.asset.resourceLoader.delegate the delegate is set correctly but it's never getting called.

I would appreciate any help with it.

Thanks,
Michal